# Is this Python script correct?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have a Programming Assignment in my class and I tried my best to understand everything but I want to make sure that my script is correct before I submit it. I need to find the area of a triangle which is given by the formula:

> Area = 1/2 * Base * Height

This is my answer:

```
# The base and height of this triangle are inches
base = 12.0
height = 16.0
# The area of a triangle is 1/2 * base * height
area = 1/2 * base * height
print (area)
```

Is my code correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because StackOverflow is not a tutorial service.

Comment: I have edited out the _huge_ amount of text to focus on what you are trying to achieve. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is indeed far better now than it was when first asked -- I'm not sure it's worth keeping open (inasmuch as it doesn't identify a *specific problem or question*), but at least it's now a better example to the OP of what a question should look like in terms of form.

Comment: In answer to your question, it is correct if you are using Python 3. In Python 2, `1/2` will return `0` because devision is handled differently. It's safer to use decimal e.g. `0.5` instead or convert one of them to `float` e.g. `area = float(1)/2 * base * height`. @CharlesDuffy that was my hope as I imagine this is a school assignment so it's not always fair for such questions to be pummeled with downvotes and either no explanation or proper guidance.

Comment: Specifically, from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, **and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**." -- there's no such description here.

Comment: Thank you, roganjosh for your help. We are using Python 3.4

Comment: it's simple maths problem, compare your python code and solve using paper, pen if both results are equal, then your script running fine.nice try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is correct, by assigning the values to different variables it is clear what you have done.